# Count the day where 'CL' In oracle report what I tried is this :

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oraclereports

Hi dear I want to count the  **CL** from rows how many CL and Multiply it with this 827 what I tried is this its generating error what will be correct please

```
function CF_CLFormula return Number is
A NUMBER;
begin
  IF :DAY_COUNT = 'CL'
    THEN
    A := COUNT(:DAY_COUNT)*827;
    RETURN A; 
    END IF;
end;
```

it gives me error of count function is used only in select, yes it is but what I can use for this and get my answer

Comment: Apart from the solution ; `RETURN A;` should be taken after `IF`..`END IF` block. Since if `:DAY_COUNT` doesn't match `'CL'`, the error will raise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work that way. You probably have to actually *count* rows from the table in a separate `SELECT` statement. Something like this:

```
function CF_CLFormula return Number is
   A NUMBER;
begin
  IF :DAY_COUNT = 'CL'
    THEN

      select count(*) * 827             --> this
        into a
        from some_table
        where day_count = 'CL';

    RETURN A; 
    END IF;
end;
```